# linux kernel driver debug log

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a Linux kernel driver for a device that has quite a bit going on and a bunch of interaction from user-space. In order to debug and troubleshoot these interactions I'm storing them in a data array in the driver and need to export this data to user-space via some sort of file node. It'd be great if I could just export the binary data and let user-space parse it into human-readable text but the requirement from other parties involved is to have this done in-driver so one can just cat the file node from the command line and get something readable.

Currently I'm just using a sysfs node but I'm pretty sure that's the wrong place for that sort of thing and I need to able to write out more than PAGE_SIZE of data. What is the proper filesystem object I should be using for this type of thing? I looked at debugfs but it seems to be for more specific things much like sysfs is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use the debugfs as its developed just for debugging purpose and only people with the necessary permission which you can decide will be able to access it.

So go ahead with using debugfs